# flutter material icons - the getter 'currency_ruble' isn't defined for the type 'Icons'

Tags: flutter, material-icons

The icon set contains the ruble currency, but if i try to add to the project i get error `The getter 'currency_ruble' isn't defined for the type 'Icons'`

```
IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.currency_ruble))
```

flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1348], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encountered the same problem with a different icon. You can try either of the following:

1. Use this regularly updated material io package and see if your ruble currency appears: [material_design_icons_flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/material_design_icons_flutter)
2. Download the png or svg and use as asset instead. [image]

Comment: Thanks! material_design_icons_flutter package solves my problem

Comment: Yes its work better

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has a cached version of the app on the device . Run

```
flutter clean
```

in your app directory.

OR check whether material icon dependency is in pubspec.yaml or not:

```
flutter:
uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the problem is not with the cache.  `uses-material-design: true` - enabled.  I opened a class `Icons`  and there is no `static const IconData` == `currency_ruble` or `currency_yuan`  the developers may have forgotten to add, I looked at the github, but the opportunity to ask questions is closed there, so I created a topic here

Answer (score 0):

There is no icons for "currency_ruble". Currencuy_ruble is not of type IconData. That's why it's showing error. If you want to use custom icon then use that icon by using Image.asset() if currency_ruble is of type image or SvgPicture.asset() if it's of type .svg

```
IconButton(onPressed: onPressed, icon: Image.asset("<image file name>"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But if you open a site with google fonts, then there is information about such an icon.  https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%3Acurrency_ruble%3A  there is also information that it is supported by flutter

Answer (score 0):

I was using 2.8.1 which didn't have latest icons. Once I upgraded the version to 2.10.5 I was able to find the missing icons.